# Adding xanthin gum to regular flour containing gluten

Tags: baking, pizza, texture, xanthan

I'm using regular bread flour and adding additional gluten when making pizza dough to get a nice stretchy dough.

Will adding xanthin gum provide any additional improvements to the texture when using flour containing gluten?

Comment: Can't answer your question because I think it's the wrong question: gluten is already very stretchy.  If your pizza dough isn't stretchy enough, then there's something wrong with your dough-making technique.

Comment: As pizza is pretty much the same thing as bread, I believe this question is already answered [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/75299/xanthan-gum-in-bread-baking?rq=1).